# Chromium wont start?

Tags: 11.10

I reinstalled chromium now it does not start at all.

I have Ubuntu 11.10 How do I check what is wrong?
Why is it so hard to post a question on here?  It keeps saying I have not met the formatting standards.

Comment: How did you install Chromium? What release (that is, version) of Ubuntu are you running? How are you launching Chromium? Is there any error message or other observable behavior when you run Chromium? Do you currently, or have you in the past, had any version of Chromium or Google Chrome installed on this Ubuntu system? Try opening a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and running the command `chromium-browser`. Then copy *all* the text from the Terminal (including what you typed) and paste it into your question. Please provide all this info by **editing your question**. That should help us help. Thx.

Comment: If you have too little information in the question it wont let you post it, it can be seen as a way to stop spam.

Answer (score -1):

## Reset Chromium settings

Issue this command in Terminal:

> rm -r ~/.config/chromium